# I want to update the data without refreshing the page when there is some changes in Firestore

Tags: node.js, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a REST with Firestore and my goal is to keep updating the result without refreshing the page when there is change in my database.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()


const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const servicAccount = require('./firebase-adminsdk.json')
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(servicAccount)
})
const db = admin.firestore()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // SSE Setup
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    });
    const doc = db.collection('TestingData').doc('uQZu5OA0XZZQtG0fKSVG');
    const observer = doc.onSnapshot(doc => res.write(doc.data()))
  });
  app.listen(3000)
```

---

Error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:696
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:696:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:661:15)
    at C:\Users\Lmaoooooooo\Desktop\Testing Firebase\index.js:19:48
    at DocumentWatch.onNext (C:\Users\Lmaoooooooo\Desktop\Testing Firebase\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:417:21)
    at DocumentWatch.pushSnapshot (C:\Users\Lmaoooooooo\Desktop\Testing Firebase\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\watch.js:449:18)
    at DocumentWatch.onData (C:\Users\Lmaoooooooo\Desktop\Testing Firebase\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\watch.js:333:26)
    at PassThrough.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lmaoooooooo\Desktop\Testing Firebase\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\watch.js:296:26)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: This is a very non-specific and broad question.  Yes, nodejs can work with any database that has an API you can reach from Javascript or some networking protocol.  Not sure what else you're asking.  If you have a specific question about Firestore, then please ask a specific question and show the code you're trying to use.  "Is there any way to implement" is NOT a specific enough question for anyone to answer.  We don't know what you're trying to do.  We don't know what code you tried?  We don't know what problems you ran into?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry for not being specific, I already edited my question and provided codes and goal. Hope you can help this time. Thank you.

Comment: The error you are getting is very descriptive and specific.  `res.write()` only takes certain argument types and you're not giving it one of the permitted types.  You're passing it an object.  Can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is very descriptive and specific. `res.write()` only takes certain argument types and you're not giving it one of the permitted types. You're passing it an object which is not permitted.

This is because `doc.data()` returns an object.  If you want the send the object as your response, then you can change things to send it as JSON like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',        // set JSON content-type
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    });
    const doc = db.collection('TestingData').doc('uQZu5OA0XZZQtG0fKSVG');
    const observer = doc.onSnapshot(doc => res.write(JSON.stringify(doc.data())));
});
```